# Rails - create by date from 2 different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have a table for a model `Score`, and a table for a model `Multiplier`. Both of these models have attributes `date` and `value`. I want to now create a new object of a different model `Total`, that corresponds to the date for `Score` and `Multiplier`. Here's the idea, though I don't think it's a good solution:

```
def create
    @scores = Score.all
    @scores.each do |score|
        Total.create(:date => score.date, :value => score.value + Multiplier.find_by_date(score.date).value)
    end
end
```

Essentially, how can I add the values of two fields from separate models to create a third object of a different model, in an elegant way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are the models associated?

Comment: total has_one score and has_one multiplier

Comment: so you have `score_id`, and `multiplier_id` in scores table and multipliers table respectively. right? also, if your `Total` model has a `date` attribute, do you want to use the date of `score` or `multiplier`? didn't think you want to use both

Comment: These are data points so the dates will be the same for a set of data points.